# I want to add my kotlin version into gradle project

Tags: android, maven, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

When I am creating a new gradle project in kotlin and add maven{
        url "https://dl.bintary.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1"
    }  this one url in my project level gradle and after downloading zip file ,I was select tool-tool window -gradle ...and trying to add that one zip file then it not added ...so simple i just want to add my kotlin version into that gradle window so that I am able to run that gradle project and please remember I am very new to this kotlin language so i didnt know anything about this.

Comment: take a look to this link it may help you [kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html)

Comment: are you trying to add kotlin extentions?

Comment: gradle project means "Android Project"? If yes you just have to check a `include kotlin` checkbox while creating project.

Comment: maven{ url "https://dl.bintary.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1" }....this code is using for what...??